# RDBMS as cache, design advice needed

Tags: database-design, relational-database, rdbms

I have a 'black box' application that gets a map of values as parameters, performs heavy and long (up to 5s) calculations and generates single `Result` which can be persisted in a database.
All I know about that application is that:

- Result is unique with respect to provided map af values
- Argument is a String->String map with known maximun length for both
  key and value
- Argument map is of variable length (from 2-3 up to 1000 entries or
  so)
- The size of list of possible key values is around 1000

Sample arguments are:

```
Map: {'k1'->'a', 'k2'->'b'} 
Map: {'k1'->'a', 'k2'->'b', ... 'k100'->'zzz'}
Map: {'k1'->'x', 'k8'->'y'}
Map: {'k6'->'z'}
```

Each of the above will produce unique `Result` object.

Now imagine another service, which is built on top of that slow library, and which needs to go online and handle dozens of calculation requests per second. 
This is impossible without caching of already calculated results. 
My estimation of total number of possible cache size is somewhat around 100-500 millions of records, which leads me towards using RDBMS as cache storage.

As the result is uniquely identified by provided map, I could sort argument map by key and concatenate it into the string 'k1:a:k2:b....'. That will definetely be the cache key, but:

- Cache key will be huge, above key size limits for many RDBMS and
  require indexed CLOB's
- I will make no use of the fact that key values are limited in
  possible values.

What'd be your advice? Performance is my main concern here.

Comment: Is it actually impossible for two different maps to produce the same result?

Comment: @Catchall, situation when different maps produce the same result is possible but is left outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this sounds more like a problem best solved by a [key-value store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_store) or [document database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Document_store), not an RDBMS.

Another possibility worth looking into is a caching server like [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Comment: Agree - this is not really relational data.

Comment: Agree twice, it took me a pretty long time to understand how much I was biased to RDBMS, redis noSql does what I want incredible faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you is to calculate how long 500M * 5sec is, expressed in days.  That is the time it will take to compute all the results that you will be storing in your cache, and that is the time it will take *before* you start to see actual benefit from having built that cache.

(Yeah, I know, you can build up your cache "gradually".  But if there are that many possible entries, then the probability of a hit is just proportional to the cache size itself, i.e. : almost none at all in the startup phase.  And it will take a looooooooooooong time before you get up to a reasonable level of hit probability.  imho.)

Comment: Good point, that's what I forgot to mention. Yes, "gradually" is what i'm really expecting. I also expect that 99% of requests will be handled by less than 1-2% of cache records.